# Is there any :below or :above pseudo class in CSS similar to :before and :after?

Tags: css

Just like `:before` and `:after` CSS pseudo classes, do we have any `:below` and `:above` pseudo classes to emulate the respective effects?

Comment: By above/below, do you mean rendered on-top-of/behind? Or do you mean parent/child in the HTML hierarchy?

Comment: @skyline3000 I meant physical positions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, here's a list of all [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes). `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes create [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) as children of your targeted element. Parent/Child is the only concept of physical position in the DOM, visual position is a matter of styling.

This means that, if you want these elements to be **visually** above/bellow their parent, you must position them as such yourself using CSS.

```css
.a {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.a::before,
.a::after {
  display: block;     /* they are inline by default */
}

.a::before { 
  content: "above";
  color: blue;
  top: -1em;  /* go above */
}

.a::after { 
  content: "bellow";
  color: red;
  top: 1em; /* go bellow */
}
```

```html
<div class="a">target</div>
```

Comment: Like you applied `relative` positioning to `.a` and `absolute` to its pseudo elements, I can't set my top level/parent element to `relative`. Do you have any idea how to tackle this problem?

Comment: We actually don't need this, my bad. We can just display them as `block`